# How to get specific index in repeated words?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two strings:

> Your beam **is** now **is** activated are yoked. #A
>
> Your beam **are yoked** now **are yoked** activated  are yoked. #B

I wanna replace "is" by "are yoked" and get the index where "is" is replaced in B string.

How could I do that?

I can't use `re.finditer()` to find them all because I would get three indices from B string.

But I only have two words to be replaced in A string.

I only want the index where "**is**" is replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.finditer(a)` to find the index of each `'is'`.

```py
import re

a = 'Your beam is now is activated are yoked.'
inds = [match.span() for match in re.finditer(r'is', a)]
print(inds) #[(10, 12), (17, 19)]
```

Comment: Yes. But what I really want is to find the indices where "is" is replaced. Not how to replace string.

Comment: Why can't you use `re.finditer()` on the first string?

Comment: Because the indices of two "are yoked" are different from "is". Even when you find out the indices of "is", you can't know the exact indices of "are yoked".